# When I Update in Custom GridView then TextBox was return null

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm trying to update data in GridView and when I click on Edit then data was bound and display in TextBox but when I click on Update and debug it then TextBox return null value and update with that null value

```
protected void grdCustomer_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtUserName = (TextBox)grdCustomer.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserName");

    command = new SqlCommand("Users_Update", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Names", txtUserName.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    grdCustomer.EditIndex = -1;
    GetData();
}
```

Comment: is this winforms or webforms?
grdCustomer.Rows[e.RowIndex] does not contain a Control with id "txtUserName" then. Check if it actually contains the control at the time of call. if this is webforms, remember that the control needs to be created in load, not in pre render

Comment: webforms and controls created in load.  sorry for late reply

Comment: When using dynamically created webform controls then at the time of the event handler call the controls need to be created. If your postback changes your controls afterwards they need to be created again in pre-render.
Please include some code that creates your gridview with that textbox control which doesn't work.

Comment: It was done with above code

Comment: before that some internal problems in my system so it wasn't run now it work perfectly. Thank You so much

Comment: @Sonai I asked how you make the textbox, not how you fetch it. But glad you figured it out now. Should probably close the question  because it doesn't apply anymore or edit it to include your internal problem and then answer yourself.

Comment: Ok Mr.Falco Ger